# magento2 fedex label generation error india

Tags: shipping, fedex, magento-2.0.7

I'm using magento2 in india store.On configuring date and following some changes.I'm able to get the rates in checkout and all.

But I cannot create shipping labels for orders.

It is showing this error :

```
An error occurred while creating shipping label.
```

Also this is what I found in logs :

```
[2016-06-29 12:07:03] main.CRITICAL: SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Fault in /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Fedex/Model/Carrier.php:1426
Stack trace:
#0 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Fedex/Model/Carrier.php(1426): SoapClient->__call('processShipment', Array)
#1 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrierOnline.php(468): Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_doShipmentRequest(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\Request))
#2 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Labels.php(163): Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline->requestToShipment(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\Request))
#3 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/LabelGenerator.php(77): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Labels->requestToShipment(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment))
#4 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(131): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator->create(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(25): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->execute()
#6 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#7 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#12 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#16 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#20 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#24 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#28 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#29 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /home/raven/Desktop/OFC/Magento/deploys/livastarm/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the debug mode on and try again. Now check in debug log, error_log and exception log to know what went wrong.

Note: The FedEx test service is down partially from yesterday. If you are using test account try after the service is up. If you are using a live account, Please check whether the live account is up and working fine.